# How to extract only a part of the string in angular / javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using time-picker to get the time :

```
<div class="timePicker-container" >
                        <md-time-picker
                        className="end-time"
                        enable-date="false"
                        (whenChange)="timeSelectionChanged($event)"
                        [disabled]="systemlogsform.value.range==='relativerange'">
                      </md-time-picker>
                      </div>
```

And timeSelectionChanged is as shown below:

```
  public timeSelectionChanged(momentTime) {
    console.log('momentTime', momentTime._d)
    }
```

This contains the below data:

`Tue Jun 15 2021 00:17:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Now , how will I be able to get only the time part , i.e. `00:17:32`  ?

Comment: Do you want the time just to display or do you actually want to store it like that? If this is just formatting to display, use the built in date pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert into Date format and get hours , minutes and seconds from there.

```
getOnlyTime(dateTimeFormat)
{
  let newFormat = new Date(dateTimeFormat);
  let hr = newFormat .getHours(); 
  let mins = newFormat .getMinutes(); 
  let secs = newFormat .getSeconds(); 

  let timeOnly = hr + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
  return timeOnly;
 }
```

You can call the method to retrieve the time.

```
let timeFormat = getOnlyTime(momentTime._d);
console.log(timeFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what package you are using to convert into the required format, but if you are using 'moment.js' package, you can take a look at this website

Link to moment.js ==> https://momentjs.com/

What you want to do is something like this:

```
var myDate = "2017-08-30T14:24:03";
console.log(moment(myDate).format("HH:mm")); // 24 hour format
console.log(moment(myDate).format("hh:mm")); // 12 hour format
console.log(moment(myDate).format("hh:mm a")); // use 'A' for uppercase AM/PM
console.log(moment(myDate).format("hh:mm:ss A")); // with milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dt = "Tue Jun 15 2021 00:17:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

const d = new Date(dt).toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
})
console.log(d)
```